# how to sum loop result (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, loops

new to this, trying to get me a little help for work, can't figure how to sum result of the loop (sum of tfa- next result just overwrites previous). thank you.

```
for (int i=0;i<=2;i++){
    NSLog(@"Input %s nozzle size", words[i]);
    float num;
    scanf("%f", &num);
    NSLog(@"%@", q1);
    float size;
    scanf("%f", &size);
    float tfa=(M_PI*pow(size/32,2)/4)*num;                    
    NSLog(@"TFA=%f", tfa );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your loop iterates, you create a new `tfa` variable, which, as you say, overwrites the previous one. So you can create a variable outside the loop, and add to it *in* the loop. Like this:

```
float tfaSum = 0;
for (int i=0;i<=2;i++){
    ...
    float tfa=(M_PI*pow(size/32,2)/4)*num;                    
    NSLog(@"TFA=%f", tfa );
    tfaSum += tfa;
}

NSLog("Sum of tfa:=%f", tfaSum);
```